# Colloquial dropping of articles - is it grammatical?

Tags: grammar, articles

There is a text:
"*I was in the forest. Trees were dark*"

If it is clear from a context what I refer to, I know native speakers tend to drop articles.

Does grammar allow it?

Comment: Your example usage isn't at all idiomatic. You could certainly get away with it in a literary/poetic context, but more likely might be *"I was in the forest. Dark trees"* - again, no article (no verb, either), but at least it's a relatively natural usage in both speech and literary contexts.

Comment: In what way do native speakers drop articles? And yes, I am implying that we don't.

Comment: Nikolay: *I went to the race. Cars were speeding around the track* is not the same as *I went to the race. Cars were fast.* The latter is not idiomatic, the former is.

Comment: Thanks guys. As I understand, leaving out articles before plurals indicates that in our opinion the listener can't identify what we mean, or we don't want him to. CarSmack, I mean in conversations. I got an example from another native speaker :)

Comment: Does grammar allow to drop "the" if the reference is absolutely clear? "I am looking at the pictures. Pictures I am looking now at are so amazing" ? Sounds funny, but anyway... :) And can we speak generally about something specific? (This really puzzles me) "I was in the forest. Trees there, when I was walking, were dark" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Articles are sometimes dropped for brevity.  Situations where this can happen include:

- news headlines,
- where one is taking notes, a statement or testimony, and needs to not write down unnecessary words - or is lazy,
- where one is listing or reciting a timeline of events,
- where space/time for communication is a premium, such as communicating over a radio

> I was in the forest. Trees were dark

Not having anything else to go on, to me, this sounds like the sentence falls under the second item above.

Comment: But when they are dropped for brevity, it is not grammatically correct, right?

Comment: Probably not.  It sounds weird if you aren't in one of those scenarios.  Maybe the best way to describe it is that it's an accepted concession in certain circumstances.  I would avoid using outside those circumstances.

Comment: And as part of Conversational Deletion ([which John Lawler has often discussed on English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/28567)).